# how to implement button click when the button is not on main layout but in a new layout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

i am not an expert in android. i want to make an app in which swiping of different layouts is there. In the MainActivity.java file, I have used viewpager. and in the MainActivity I hv not declared any button since the main.xml file does not contain any UI component.My question is how to implement
button click where button is on another layout i.e. right.xml file.

```
    //This is my opening screen containing button
public class Right extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
      {
         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.right);
         Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
           b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View arg0) {
              Intent i = new Intent(Right.this, Left.class);
              startActivity(i);
              }
           });
      }
}
```

Comment: You want to implement a click on a button. And this button is not on visible layout ? if yes it's not possible and very strange

Comment: You're not being clear. Can you elaborate? Why do you want to use button present in different layout? Your approach might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use `TabHost` widget with `PageViewer`. And you will have to create some `fragments` to run your layouts where you will have to use `getActivity()` instead of `Right.this`. With the help of `PageViewer` you can swipe your each fragment with their layouts. We extend `FragmentActivity` in `MainActivity` and extend `Fragments` to run layouts.

Answer (score 0):

please refer - http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/09/android-switching-between-activities-example.html
or
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/how-to-switch-between-activities-in-android/
or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743094/how-to-switch-between-activities-screens-in-android
or
http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/invoke-activity-from-another-activity.html#.VOW9xeaUenA
or
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFzD43FS5vE

Comment: thanks tod , Where it is mentioned? Can you please send me link of that?