# android code for switching between activities

Tags: android-activity

In an activity there are 2 buttons. 1st button should open one activity and the 2nd button should open another activity. The following code is what I wrote. Please help me.

```
    Button voice;
    Button msg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_type_of_msg);
        voice=(Button)findViewById(R.id.voice);
        msg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId()==R.id.voice)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(), TypeOfMsgActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice_msg);
        }
        else if(view.getId()==R.id.text)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TypeOfMsgActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_msg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please format your text correctly next time, by using ctrl+k as shotcut to include code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to switch between activities/screens in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743094/how-to-switch-between-activities-screens-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

```
Replace this;

    `Button voice;
    Button msg;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_type_of_msg);
        voice=(Button)findViewById(R.id.voice);
voice.setOnClickListener(this);
        msg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.text);
msg.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId()==R.id.voice)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(), TypeOfMsgActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice_msg);
        }
        else if(view.getId()==R.id.text)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TypeOfMsgActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_msg);
        }

    }`


By this:

    Button voice;
    Button msg;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_type_of_msg);
        voice=(Button)findViewById(R.id.voice);
        msg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.text);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.voice:
            Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(), TypeOfMsgActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            break;
        case R.id.text:
             Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TypeOfMsgActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);



            break;


        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

Also implements OnClickListener  in your class

Answer (score 1):

***please try below code:***

```
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {    public void onClick(View v)
        {
            intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {    public void onClick(View v)
        {
            intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```